# efficiency way to get the coordinate of each rectangle box

Tags: python, image, coordinates

I am trying to get the coordinates from a Zoom image.
Suppose there are 20 "boxes" inside Zoom image.  Is there any way to
get each box coordinate (upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right)?

I am trying different methods likes Canny edge detection / erosion by Python opencv
but it will also get the "content" inside the zoom image box which I don't expect to use.
I only need the "red circle" (ref to the image)

[image]
[image]

Thanks
Alex

Comment: If the images are all separated nicely by a constant color (black?) background, then you can just floodfill, for example or threshold and get the bounding boxes from the contours.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  However, if the content inside the box contains the same color, it will also be fill.  This similar to the edge detection (the pic I show).

Comment: But often even if filled partially inside, you can use morphology to close up and can still get the contour and/or convex hull and reduce to 4 corners or just get the bounding box.